# How do i extract a Date from datetime field in Advantage SQL DB

Tags: sql

I have a DateTime field called Created.  I want to just get the date from that and no time.  In Normal MS SQL I've used Cast/Convert functions, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in advantage SQL?

```
select CAST(created as date)
from matrstep
```

> poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2159;  [SAP][Advantage SQL Engine]Invalid argument to scalar function: CAST - unrecognized data type: date. -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 8

Comment: Interesting . . . Advantage claims to support `date`:  http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.0/server1/adt_field_types_and_specifications.htm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this site](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.0/supported_statements/miscellaneous_functions.htm) I think following might work:

```
select CAST(created as sql_date)
from matrstep
```